# How can I make "gradle --stacktrace" the default?

Tags: gradle

Is there a way I can set `--info` or `--stacktrace` via `gradle.properties`?

I currently have a gazillion build scripts that end up invoking gradle at some point, and I would like to standardize the error handling behavior across the board.

Comment: One way would be to edit the script files in the bin directory to add those arguments.

Comment: Or I can "wrap the wrapper", but then devs who don't have my wrapper don't get the same behavior as on my build hosts.

Comment: How about using the gradle-wrapper and making the required changes in the wrapper (you could even use it to point to a customized gradle implementation with your changes if required). This can then be distributed to all the developers.

Comment: If you do that, the change might get clobbered if the wrapper is regenerated. This being said, I'll try GRADLE_OPTS... nope, that's for JVM opts, not for gradle.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not in `gradle.properties` but in `build.gradle` itself. Add the following piece of code at the very beginning of the build script:

```
import org.gradle.logging.ShowStacktrace
gradle.startParameter.showStacktrace = ShowStacktrace.ALWAYS
throw new RuntimeException('lol')
```

Or in Android Studio:

```
import org.gradle.api.logging.configuration.ShowStacktrace
gradle.startParameter.showStacktrace = ShowStacktrace.ALWAYS
```

It also might be put in [init script](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).

As pointed out in the comments, from gradle v. 2.14 it will be:

```
gradle.startParameter.showStacktrace = org.gradle.api.logging.configuration.ShowStacktrace.ALWAYS
```

Comment: If you don't see the stacktrace use the [org.gradle.api.logging.configuration.ShowStacktrace.ALWAYS_FULL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/logging/configuration/ShowStacktrace.html) enum value

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74994722/253468

Answer (score 8):

Since Gradle 7.4 this is possible through `gradle.properties`.

```
org.gradle.logging.stacktrace=all
```

Docs: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties

Added in https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/18713

Answer (score 2):

There is another approach where you do not have to edit the `build.gradle` file because you may not want it so verbose when you run your CI. In addition, you now have to remember to turn it off in CI. So, instead, you can limit to the IDE. If you are using eclipse, you can follow these steps to apply it only to gradle runs within your IDE.

Run -> "Run Configurations" -> Select "Gradle Project" -> Click "Project Settings" tab -> Click "Configure project settings..." link -> Select "Override workspace settings" -> paste "--stacktrace" in "Program Arguments" text field.

The above worked with Spring Tool Suite 4.2.1 which is based on Eclipse 4.11.0.x