# Add '--warning-mode all' command line argument in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am getting the following message when I compile an Android Studio project:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
```

How do I add the '--warning-mode all' command line setting to my Android Studio project so I can find the deprecated feature?

Comment: You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680263/4693331) post. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: List deprecated features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304438/gradle-list-deprecated-features)

Comment: @Artipatel uh, just noticed your comment here, after answering with the same suggestion

Answer (score 78):

Just create a file called [gradle.properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) in your root project:

```
root 
|--gradle.properties 
|--build.gradle 
|--app 
|----build.gradle
```

Then add inside that file:

> org.gradle.warning.mode=(all,none,summary)

Comment: Thanks, working, but this must be an incredibly ridiculous way of doing it? Is there really not available a setting somewhere? It is 2019!

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i was looking for =)

Comment: @carl I believe this is a great solution. It allows you to share this important setting on version control with your whole team to avoid the "works on my machine" problem. And the IDE is picking it up automatically, which is great too. I imagine IntelliJ could have a setting that would generate this file for you.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me with with latest Android Studio and Gradle versions. Fortunately, @Superjos's answer works like a charm.

Comment: Installed AS and Gradle latest last month. When I click Build->Clean_Project it reported `Value '(all,none,summary)' given for org.gradle.warning.mode Gradle property is invalid`. The root gradle.properties file was already there, as I expected. What worked instead was: `org.gradle.warning.mode=all`

Comment: @John you have to choose between all, none or summary

Answer (score 51):

Please have a look at this older [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304438/gradle-list-deprecated-features), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54680263/540776).

Just pasting the same picture here, but credits should go to original answer author:

[image: Settings\Compiler, Command-line Options]

Comment: I recommend Zain's answer when working in a team with version control, as that one allows everyone to build using the same settings. E.g I have `org.gradle.warning.mode=fail` and I want that to happen in my machine, my coworkers machine, the CI machine, etc.

Comment: This one about version control is quite a sensible aspect to take into account, definitely

Comment: @MartínColl if you share the project settings, this one is stored "For currrent project", so you should be able to share it across the computers, I guess (not expert in version control environments, just saying it might be possible)

Comment: @Edw590 Thanks for your point that it is stored for current project. However, when I searched, I didn't see where the settings from here are stored. Not in gradle.properties, not in .idea folder, etc. ; in fact, I tried a "find" over the entire project folders, and got no results; any idea where it might be?

Comment: @auspicious99 Hi! You may not have searched right. Just searched here and it's inside .idea/workspace.xml on COMMAND_LINE_OPTIONS. If it matters, I searched with Notepad++ (to be sure it searches exactly all the files, since the IDE ignores some).

Comment: @Edw590 thanks for helping to check! Indeed, it IS there in COMMAND_LINE_OPTIONS. So I guess it would be shared across computers if and only if .idea/workspace.xml is added to the git repo. Cool, good to know..

Answer (score 28):

Add this

```
org.gradle.warning.mode=all
```

in Gradle Scripts  -> gradle.properties(Project Properties)
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This error is currently being caused by the shutdown of jcenter.

"The RepositoryHandler.jcenter() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. JFrog announced JCenter's shutdown in February 2021. Use mavenCentral() instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: [https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation"](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#jcenter_deprecation%22)

Answer (score 2):

In **Gradle** **7.3.3.** , You can just write in the Terminal

```
 .\gradlew --warning-mode all
```

or

```
.\gradlew --stacktrace
```