# Stacktrace option for Gradle task in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, stack-trace

A Gradle task `classesPipeline` is being run in Eclipse. This task assembles `.class` files by depending on the standard `classes` task, then attempts executing a batchfile.

All goes fine until the batchfile, where the script dies a horrible death in Eclipse, by printing to console:

```
Execution failed for task ':classesPipeline'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command '../SomeFolder/SomeBatchfile.bat''

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

The log suggests to run the task with `--stacktrace`, but how do  I do this?

So I checked the project settings, the Gradle section offers no command line arguments, as far as i see. It is noteworthy, that running the task with `--stacktrace` via *gradlew*  is of no value to me, because the task executes just fine in this case, this is only happening in Eclipse specifically.

TL;DR:

How can a gradle task be executed from Eclipse, while passing arguments to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone who may come into contact with this problem:

I found the solution in a different, but closely related question:

[How can I make "gradle --stacktrace" the default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977196/how-can-i-make-gradle-stacktrace-the-default)

It is sufficient to add the following to the `build.gradle`:

```
gradle.startParameter.showStacktrace = org.gradle.api.logging.configuration.ShowStacktrace.ALWAYS
```